# Post-Export-APK event command line Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I would like to copy *.apk file to remote location after APK-Export in Xamarin.
Just like post-build events for building.
Where should I put commands for this?

How can I achieve this using VS2015 + Xamarin?